# Why is my pandas data frame not converting rightly into columns and rows to pyspark's data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pyodbc

I am trying to read data from sql server and then creating pyspark data frame.

I have tried creating a specific schema for it as well, but that too isn't helping

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

mySchema = StructType([ StructField("CAMP_ID", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("SEG_ID", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("CUST_NAME", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("CUST_CNIC", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("CUST_GENDER", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("CUST_DOB", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("CUST_MOBILE", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("CUST_EMAIL", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("PAN", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("TRAN_DATE", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("TRAN_CURRENCY", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("TRAN_AMOUNT", FloatType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("STAN", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("MERCHANT_CAT_CODE", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("MERCHANT_NAME", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("MERCHANT_TYPE", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("TRAN_LOCATION", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("RESPONSE_NAME", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("CHANNEL_NAME", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("NETWORK_NAME", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("ACCT_STATUS_NAME", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("ACCT_TYPE_NAME", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("card_status", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("product_code", StringType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf,schema=mySchema)
```

[image: This is the dataframe I have]

[image: this is the result that am getting]

Comment: try display(df)

Comment: Could you please point me to the error? The data seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior. If you want to pretty print it, try:

```
display(df)
```

If you want only first two rows, you can try something like

```
df.take(2)
```

But it won't be pretty printed.